# Using HTACCESS how can I rewrite example.php to /example2.php regardless of what folder example1.php is in

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So, for example,

```
fakesite.com/folder1/example1.php
fakesite.com/folder2/folder2a/example1.php
fakesite.com/folder3/example1.php
```

all would rewrite example1.php with the content of . . .

```
fakesite.com/example2.php
```

This would be happening with a lot of files on the server in various folders, so a simple rewrite would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Apache, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule example1.php /example2.php [L]
```

This really is pretty basic for mod_rewrite, googling "apache rewrite examples" will give you this.

Comment: This worked.  Very embarrassing. I googled like crazy, my mistake was in assuming it was more complicated.

Comment: @user1464545 The trick is to use a regular expression that only looks for `example1.php` as opposed to trying to match the entire URI

Comment: @user1464545 Also you should accept the answer so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions